# Failed send mail code 550

Tags: email, dns

I am having a nightmare trying to get an email to send through on a form on my site I am working on for a client.

I initially realized it did not have the TXT records in the DNS settings like so:

```
**Record type: TXT
Hostname: website.mysite.co.uk 
Value: v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all
Record type: TXT
Hostname: mx._domainkey.website.mysite.co.uk
Value: k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDOBpdR3hItAZ7McucH8eZ8C79HoAGyFRLWDfq5ecU8NKSO/E/HjHbsiwczbjqHChN2LPMLXccWL0v3PLYOeXqKffsUGr6S99gP1M2lxuCnW8z4AE232F7dUjzdeEdrqWN/z10VPRs6ZfbbO/6Uh3Z6afH74NL+v3EvIK2Gbmz9GwIDAQAB**
```

However, a day has passed and from mailgun everything is verified and should be working. When contacting the support team from the clients hosting provider, they had said that they do not provide dns hosting for anyone they dont provide websites or email or software to.

But why did it let me add the records in the first place if this is the case? They said I would have to release the domain to us.

I'm just curious if anyone has came across this issue before and I'm worried about releasing a clients domain somewhere else and the problem still persisting.

This is the email error logs I received for the emails I tried sending through on the form.

```
**Failed: mail@website.mysite.co.uk → sd@mysite.co.uk 'Enquiry'

Server response: 550 550 Verification failed for 
                 <bounce+181f62.33cab-sd=mysite.co.uk@website.mysite.co.uk>
                 The mail server could not deliver mail to 
                 bounce+181f62.33cab-sd=mysite.co.uk@website.mysite.co.uk.
                 The account or domain may not exist, they may be             
                 blacklisted,  or missing the proper dns entries. 

Sender verify failed**
```

Comment: How are you sending those emails?

Comment: any solution?? I have similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error (which is called Sender Address Verification)

I go to WHm to change Exim configuration as

**WHM: Main >> Service Configuration >> Exim Configuration Editor >> Standard Options >> Mai**l

then put

**Sender Verification Callouts -> off
Sender Verification -> off**

Then everything is working fine.